# flutter: why I cannot use the final member field as the padding of widget?

Tags: dart, flutter

I write the following widget:

```
class Bottombar extends StatelessWidget {
  final double padding;
  Bottombar({@required this.padding});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(padding), child: new Text('Test'),);
  }
}
```

However, it reports compiling error that the padding parameter must be constant expressions. Why cannot use the final member field as the parameter of widget padding? For what reason?

The flutter version is beta 0.3.1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is you're using `const` to create the `EdgeInsets` but then passing a variable `padding`.

Remove `const` and it should work.